# Smallest partition in a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, numerical-methods, combinations, computer-science

I have a set consisting of

$$\Omega = \{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n\}$$

and I have to obtain another set, formed by the sum of the elements of the first set, such that the new elements do not exceed a certain constant $c$. However, that set must be the set that has the least number of elements possible.
An example,

$$\Omega = \{5, 10, 10, 14, 20\}$$
If $c = 20$, let $s_1 = \{\{5, 10\}, \{10\}, \{14\}, \{20\}\}$ and $s_2 = \{ \{10, 10\}, \{5, 14\}, \{20\}\}$.

If $s_1$ and $s_2$ were the only two sets that meet the constraint (sum of elements less than or equal to 20), $s_2$ would be selected, because $\#(s_2) < \#(s_1)$.

A possible solution to my problem would be to generate all possible sets, check which ones meet the criteria and get the smallest one. However, this solution became unfeasible for a set ($ \Omega $) of 16 elements. Would anyone have a better approach, or any suggestions on how to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance and sorry for the informality.

Comment: Are you always guaranteed that the elements are listed in increasing order? That is, $a_{k} \leq a_{k+1}$? If so, you partition by adding until you reach $c$ and then start the next subset. Make sense?

Comment: Waldon, not sure, apply this approach, however, for a set with 12 elements it approaches me as a partition of 6 elements, however, there is another partition with 5. I will leave the set as an example, for $c = 533$, $\Omega = \{16,132,135,135,136,138,138,139,301,334,355,361\}$

Comment: Even one of your sets above is a counterexample...My bad. I am not so sure what a good way is then. This adding trick at least gives a partition which is "close" to the correct number of elements I think? It could narrow the search by brute-force.

Comment: True, this trick approaches, however, I am in a scenario that I need to guarantee the optimum. Brute force is the only way I know of, but even so, I'm not getting it due to computational time.

Comment: This is called the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

Comment: Thanks Rob, it's a famous problem that I didn't know about.